# ArchUnits layeredArchitecture rule doesn't include fields

Tags: archunit

We check our software architecture by some ArchUnit rules.

One of this is the test for our layered architecture.

This works fine for methods.
If we access a method of layer3 from layer1 we will get an exception.

But if the access a field declared in layer3 from layer1 this won't throw an exception.

```
   .layer("layer1").definedBy("com.acme.layer1")
   .layer("layer2").definedBy("com.acme.layer2")
   .layer("layer3").definedBy("com.acme.layer3")
   .whereLayer("layer3").mayNotBeAccessedByAnyLayer()
   .whereLayer("layer2").mayOnlyAccessedByLayers("layer3")
   .as("Respect the layered architecture");
```

This won't throw an exception if we import a field from layer3 to a layer1 class:

```
package com.acme.layer1

import static com.acme.layer3.SOME_LABEL

public class x {
   ...
}
```

Our expectation is that also accessing fields from layer3 in any other layer should throw an exception.
Or is there another way to check?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My answer depends on the assumption that `com.acme.layer3.SOME_LABEL` is a [constant expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28) like `public static final String SOME_LABEL = "..."`

Compile-time constants are inlined during compilation. If your code looks like

```
String label = SharedConstants.SOME_LABEL;
```

then the compiled bytecode contains the *exact value* of `SharedConstants.SOME_LABEL`. There remains no reference to this field in the bytecode. ([The Static Final Inline Trap](http://javasplitter.blogspot.com/2011/10/static-final-inline-trap.html))

ArchUnit gathers all information by analyzing the bytecode, see also the [ArchUnit User Guide](https://www.archunit.org/userguide/html/000_Index.html#_introduction). Because there is no information about `SharedConstants.SOME_LABEL` in the bytecode, ArchUnit doesn't know about this access.

In summary: This is a limitation of ArchUnit and all other libraries which only depend on the bytecode.